# Isso é um bug no stdClass?

Tags: php

No PHP é possível declarar uma variável ao mesmo tempo que passamos ela como parâmetro de uma função ou na instanciação da classe.

Vou dar um exemplo com a função `is_file` e a classe `ArrayObject`.

```
$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($a = []);

var_dump($a); // Imprime: array(0) {}


is_file($b = 'index.php');

print_r($b); // Imprime: "index.php";
```

Porém, quando fazemos isso no `stdClass`, algo inesperado acontece.

```
$object = new stdClass($c = []);

print_r($c); //Undefined variable 'c'
```

**Nota**: Para comprovarem que eu não estou inventando, aí vai o código no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/LqbApv)

**Atualização**: Devido as respostas postadas falarem a respeito de *ter a ver com os parâmetros existirem no construtor da classe ou da função, ou não* para que a atribuição aconteça quando atribuímos o valor a uma variável que ao mesmo tempo passamos como parâmetro, estou colocando um código de exemplo para comprovar que isso não é verdade.

Criei três cenários.

- A primeira classe `ComParametro` aceita apenas um parâmetro no construtor
- A segunda classe `SemParametro` não aceita nenhum paràmetro no construtor, como no caso do `stdClass`
- E por último, temos o `stdClass`.

Vejamos:

```
class ComParametro
{
   public function __construct($parametro){}
}


class SemParametro
{
    public function __construct(){}
}

new ComParametro($a = 'a');


print_r($a);

new SemParametro($b = 'b');

print_r($b);

new stdClass($c = 'c');

print_r($c);
```

Como podemos ver no [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/5WuXmJ), os resultados foram respectivamente:

```
a
b
Undefined variable 'c'
```

Então, o que quero saber é por que esse comportamento está presente no `stdClass`!

Comment: *Para comprovarem que eu não estou inventando...* :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não sei como o PHP trata esse caso, mas se uma classe não tem definido o construtor(que é o caso `stdClass`), então qualquer atribuição será inválida na hora da instanciação do objeto.

**Exemplo**

```
<?php
class aa {
  function __construct() {}
}

class bb {
}

new aa($a = []);

var_dump($a);

new bb($b = []);

var_dump($b);
```

Comment: Se eu tiver uma classe que não aceita parâmetros no construtor, a atribuição vai acontecer corretamente. Vou postar um exemplo!

Comment: Veja de alguma forma quando definimos um construtor, a atribuição é válida, mas quando não definimos o construtor a atribuição não é.

Comment: O problema então não está na questão da parametrização. Deu para entender pelo seu exemplo que, quando instanciamos a classe, o construtor não é chamado (pois não há construtor). Então o interpretador do PHP não cria a variável internamente por conta disso. Ou seja, a questão não é o construtor sem parâmetros, é que, não existindo ele, o interpretador do PHP não processa o que é passado por parâmetro no `stdClass` ou qualquer outra classe sem `__construct`. Legal :)

Comment: Agora o +1 foi mais que merecido. As respostas não estavam erradas, mas faltava então explicar que `__construct()` sem parâmetro não é a mesma coisa de não ter o `__construct`. Loucura, loucura, loucura!

Comment: PHP tem dessas coisa 1 = true, null = false...

Answer (score 2):

`stdClass` não aceita parâmetros.

A melhor forma de definir um valor como este para `sdtClass` é uma conversão:

```
$std = (object)$c = [];

var_dump($std); // Retorna object(stdClass)#1 (0) {}
var_dump($c); // Retorna array(0) {}
```

Portanto NÂO, esta é a definição da classe e não um bug.

Comment: O que está sendo discutido aqui é que: Se o PHP aceita declarar variáveis ao mesmo tempo que a passamos por parâmetro, por que não é assim em `stdClass` (em qualquer outra classe, é assim)

Comment: Detalhe,, `stdClass` tem uma forma específica de ser usada o que faz com que mesmo que você passe qualquer parâmetros pra ela, ela desconsidera, mesmo que seja a você setando uma variável. isso nunca funcionou e não há previsão de que essa classe passará a fazer isso, então sim, este é um caso específico que foge às regras gerais do *PHP*. e não é o único caso que o *php* quebra suas próprias regras. :D

Comment: +1 por editar a resposta e deixar mais claro, a sua resposta é boa, eu faço desse jeito também.

Comment: Ainda vocês não entenderam o sentido da pergunta

Comment: @ErlonCharles, você fez um cast, para converter `array` para `object` (Ou o `stdClass`). A resposta ainda assim não tem a ver com a pergunta que eu fiz. Não perguntei sobre como funciona a instância do `stdClass`, mas porque esse comportamento só está presente nele. Não estamos tratando do assunto "instância", e sim "variáveis definidas ao mesmo tempo que passadas com parâmetro dando pau"

Comment: Mas sua pergunta é especificamente "Isso é um bug no stdClass?". Portanto há sim uma resposta para sua pergunta na primeira e na última linha da minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Para reforçar mais ainda a nossa teoria em relação à pergunta, vou dar o meu pitaco a respeito do assunto.

Como exemplificado pelo nosso amigo, a questão não é o fato de ter um construtor ou função com ou sem parâmetros. Isso não afeta em nada em relação a variável passada por argumento.

Os exemplos abaixo causarão a atribuição das variáveis:

```
function a(){}

class b
{
   public function __construct(){}
}

a($a = 1);
new b($b = 2);

var_dump($a, $b); // Imprime 1 e 2
```

Já no caso do construtor não ser definido, ocorre o problema descrito na pergunta:

```
class C{}

new C($c = 3);

var_dump($c); // Undefined variable 'c'
```

Essa é uma questão que provavelmente está relacionada ao interpretador do PHP.
Se a classe não tiver construtor, então não há necesidade de processar o que é passado por parâmetro de instância da classe - talvez pensaram assim quando fizeram a codificação das classes.

A última coisa que temos que fazer então é verificar se o `stdClass` realmente não possui o `__construct` internamente - apenas para meios de provas concretas.

Então, vamos lá:

```
$object = new stdClass;

$reflector = new ReflectionClass($object);

var_dump($reflector->getConstructor()); // NULL
```

Já em `ArrayObject`

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass(new ArrayObject());

var_dump($reflector->getConstructor());
```

A saída é :

```
class ReflectionMethod#4 (2) {
  public $name =>
  string(11) "__construct"
  public $class =>
  string(11) "ArrayObject"
}
```

Então está provado que não existe `__construct` na classe `stdClass`

Comment: Depois também dá para fazer coisas como esta, é por isso que eu gosto do PHP :)